# Add Cell value into URL to find Data vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace `558899` this Id number from below URL with cell value that is `ID_NO = ws.Range("A1").Value`.

```
"15.156.352.352/api/Book/GetOrBookID?Id=558899&ColumnName=PrimaryId"
```

and i changed it to

```
"15.156.352.352/api/Book/GetOrBookID?Id=" & ID_NO & "ColumnName=PrimaryId"
```

But it does not work nay help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't mention what the bad result is, but I can see one issue in your code:

```
"15.156.352.352/api/Book/GetOrBookID?Id=" & ID_NO & "ColumnName=PrimaryId"
```

When this is parsed, it will result in:

```
"15.156.352.352/api/Book/GetOrBookID?Id=xxxxColumnName=PrimaryId"
```

But I think you want:

```
"15.156.352.352/api/Book/GetOrBookID?Id=xxxx&ColumnName=PrimaryId"
```

So the code you need is:

```
"15.156.352.352/api/Book/GetOrBookID?Id=" & ID_NO & "&ColumnName=PrimaryId"
```

Comment: Thank you very much exactly i was missing this `&` that how to include it. Thank you @CLR

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that the cell value is formatted as a number(long). therefore you could try replacing ID_NO with str(ID_NO) to convert it to a string